# How to write using poll function in linux?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, operating-system, system-calls

I am new to Linux and I am learning the Linux system calls via the C program. I came up with the function called poll() in the Multiplexed IO topic. I am unable to understand how to write to a specific file and when I tried to write the input into a file, it's writing successfully but no "TIMEOUT" is occurring and the return value of the poll() is "1". Please help with which appropriate flag has to be used in the open() while opening the file. Thanks in advance. Since I am new to this topic, please explain which I misunderstood in this concept. The code which I tried is attached below.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<poll.h>

int main() {


        int fd;
        int timeout = 5000;
        struct pollfd fds[2];

        int fd1 = 0;
        char buff[11];

        while(1) {

                fds[0].fd = fd1;
                fds[0].events = POLLIN;

                fd = open("/home/user/samplefiles/File.txt", O_WRONLY);
                fds[1].fd = fd;
                fds[1].events = POLLOUT;

                int ret = poll(fds, 2, timeout); //returns 1 

                printf("        Ret = %d\n", ret);
                if (ret == 0) {
                        printf("        Timeout\n");
                        continue;
                }

                read(fd1, buff, 10);
                write(fd, buff, 10);
                printf("written buff = %s\n", buff);
        }
}
```

Comment: What kind of file is `/home/user/samplefiles/File.txt`? A regular file? A FIFO?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yeah Its a regular file

Comment: What do you expect `poll` to tell you about a regular file?

Comment: You need to check the `revents` fields of the pollfd array to see which events have happened.

Comment: Also iirc a regular file is *always* going to immediately poll as writable.

Comment: You also need to pay attention to `read()` return value and use it to know how much to `write()`. Plus error checking and handling everywhere.